# Jwplayer 6.11 doesn't show controllers buttons

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I upgrade jyplayer to 6.11, but now in playing controlls button doesn't appear, also i try it with skin. screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/rk4kdc.png

And for loading the video i try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jwplayer("mediaplayer_test-_internet_archive.mp4").setup({
    flashplayer: "http://localhost:8080/elements/player.swf",
    file: "http://localhost:8080/test.mp4",
    skin: "http://localhost:8080/elements/skins/five.xml",
    html5player: "http://localhost:8080/elements/jwplayer.html5.js",
    width: 420,
    height: 290
  });
});
```

When click on the screen playing start and pause when again click, but icon doesn't appear. I used it with skin six, five and without skin (default) and again this issue shows.

Comment: You're pointing to player.swf, which is from JW Player 5. But there appears to be something else lousing up the basic JW6 CSS, as well. The fact that the logo is in the wrong place is a tip-off. We'll need a link to your site to debug it.

Comment: Oh, and if jwplayer.html5.js and jwplayer.flash.swf are in the same directory as jwplayer.js, you don't need the "flashplayer" and "html5player" attributes at all. The jwplayer.js script automatically looks for the other two (if it needs them) in its own location, unless told otherwise.

Comment: I removed both of flashplayer and html5player. But, again the same result!

Comment: Same comment - we need a link to the actual page. The code snippet doesn't tell us anything. No one can debug a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer_test-_internet_archive.mp4").setup({
```

To:

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer_test-_internet_archive_mp4").setup({
```

The period is messing up things.